# Overload the 'space' operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++11

I have a little bit of experience in C++.  I know how to overload the plus sign and what not, but would like to overload the space operator.

For example:

```
MyObject obj();

result = obj - foo; // This would be treated as a normal '-' operation.

result = obj-foo; // This would invoke code which throws an assert at runtime
```

This would allow me to enforce certain style guidelines I'm trying to set forth for my team.

Comment: First of all, obj is a function name, not an object.

Comment: err I don't think "space" is an operator it is a way for the parser to tokenize things, at best.

Comment: Space is not an operator. Use actual static code analysis, not convoluted operator overloading.

Comment: Are you sure?  I thought one of the strengths of C++0x was that you could overload anything and practically redefine the language.

Comment: This question is scaring on several levels. The least is that someone claiming a little bit of experience in C++ (which is vague, but it seems to include knowledge about operator overloads) is unaware of the utter irrelevance of whitespace, even assuming it's an operator.

Comment: Even if the space operator existed, enforcing coding guidelines at runtime is just begging for trouble.  In that case, *users* will experience runtime crashes when the coding guidelines are not followed.

Answer (score 9):

There is no space operator in C++. Whitespace is not significant in most cases, there is no difference from a parsing point of view between

```
a-b
```

and

```
a -      b
```

Which I'm happy for.

Note: there are some corner cases (nested templates spring to mind) where it actually matters, but that's more of an artifact of the grammar than indications of the whitespace being active as an "operator", in my opinion.

Comment: Now, to be pedantic and to make things slightly more complicated, it sometimes does matter if there are spaces (1 or more, *that* doesn't matter) or not. Exactly every time the lack of spaces would allow the (greedy) tokenizer to tokenize differently. The most obvious example would be variable names (you can't have spaces in a name), but it can also ruin e.g. preincrememt (`+ + x` is just `x` and has no side effects, `++x` is preincrement).

Comment: To be pedantic again ;) It's a result of how tokenizers work, but a necessary evil to keep them simple and predictable (just take the first thing that matches and match as much as possible - instead of trying to figure out possible interpretations). Yes, it doesn't assign whitespace any meaning post tokenization, much less make it an operator.

Comment: For another example, the preprocessor distinguishes a function-style macro from a macro with `(` as the first substituted character by the presence of whitespace between the macro name and the paren. `#define fn( x )` takes an argument, `#define fn ( x )` does not.

Answer (score 7):

Bjarne Stroustrup *did* at one time suggest [allowing overloading of whitespaces](https://www.stroustrup.com/whitespace98.pdf) [PDF]. But seeing as this article was published on April 1<sup>st</sup> he may not have been 100% serious...

The article is worth a read though.

Comment: I heard this was implemented at the new data center: http://www.google.com/jobs/lunar_job.html (also published on April 1st).

Answer (score 3):

There is no such item as the whitespace operator.  In general in C++ whitespace is irrelevant and doesn't cause functionality differences in the program, hence there's nothing to overload.

What you're looking for is a static analysis tool for C++.  Something akin to StyleCop for C++.  Unfortunately I don't have a lot of experience in this area and can't recommend a specific program.  Likely someone else on this thread will be able to though.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, not possible.

Instead look at code formatters - there are a few for every popular IDE (for example checkstyle for eclipse), or you can setup pre-commit hook in your version control system server, that checks if code before and after formattting is the same, and if not, it returns error instead of allowing to commit the code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. Space is not an operator. If you want to enforce style, use static code analysis tools and talk to your team members. Try cpplint or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enforce style guidelines, obtain a tool or application that can identify violations of style.  A tool that can do this is Klocwork.  There are probably smaller and simpler tools out there.

Worst case, write your own.

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend a look at Guy Steele's new HPC language: [Fortress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_programming_language). It allows the overloading of the *juxtaposition* operator. There's also a blog post covering this aspect [here](http://janusnielsen.wordpress.com/fortress/introduction/). It's not going to help you with formatting, but it's rather funky. (Haskell and ML also use juxtaposition to apply functions).